# Como realizar .filter entre arrays/objetos AngularJS Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Tenho os dois seguintes objetos no AngularJS:

```html
$scope.listaDoCarrinho = [0: {
        id: "55",
        setor: "alimento",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (55).jpg",
        descr: "Espaguete Renata",
        de: 15,
        …
    }
    1: {
        id: "1000",
        setor: "biscoitos",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (1000).jpg",
        descr: "Biscoito Pit-Stop",
        de: 3,
        …
    }
    2: {
        id: "3",
        setor: "higiene",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (3).jpg",
        descr: "Bronzeador 200ml",
        de: 15,
        …
    }
];

$scope.listademercadoria1 = [0: {
        id: "55",
        setor: "alimento",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (55).jpg",
        descr: "Espaguete Renata",
        de: 15,
        …
    }
    1: {
        id: "1000",
        setor: "biscoitos",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (1000).jpg",
        descr: "Biscoito Pit-Stop",
        de: 3,
        …
    }
    2: {
        id: "197",
        setor: "sobremesa",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (197).jpg",
        descr: "Nutella",
        de: 10,
        …
    }
    4: {
        id: "1",
        setor: "higiene",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (1).jpg",
        descr: "Bronzeador",
        de: 200,
        …
    }
];
```

Eu preciso de um comando .filter que me retorne `$scope.listademercadoria1 - $scope.listaDoCarrinho` (Variável listademercadoria1 menos a variável listaDoCarrinho), filtradas pelo `id`.

Depois de muito pesquisar, cheguei nessas conclusões abaixo, porém infuncionais:

Tentativa 1:

```html
$scope.listaMercadoriaNova = $scope.listademercadoria1.filter(

    $scope.listademercadoria1.id = $scope.listaDoCarrinho.id);
```

Tentativa 2:

```html
$scope.listaMercadoriaNova = $scope.listademercadoria1.filter(
    function() {
        return $scope.listademercadoria1.id != $scope.listaDoCarrinho.id;
    });

$scope.listademercadoria1 = $scope.listaMercadoriaNova;
```

Acho que ficou bem explicado, qualquer coisa que eu puder melhorar a explicação, todo comentário é bem vindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que precisas é, por exemplo:

```
const filtrados = $scope.listademercadoria1.filter(
    obj => $scope.listaDoCarrinho.find(item => obj.id == item.id)
);
```

Assim procuras em cada `listademercadoria1` se existe esse ID em `listaDoCarrinho`. Caso não exista, remove-o do retorno do `.filter()`.

Exemplo:

```js
// só para o exemplo funcionar
$scope = {};
// só para o exemplo funcionar

$scope.listaDoCarrinho = [{
  id: "55",
  setor: "alimento",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (55).jpg",
  descr: "Espaguete Renata",
  de: 15
}, {
  id: "1000",
  setor: "biscoitos",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (1000).jpg",
  descr: "Biscoito Pit-Stop",
  de: 3,
}, {
  id: "3",
  setor: "higiene",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (3).jpg",
  descr: "Bronzeador 200ml",
  de: 15,
}];

$scope.listademercadoria1 = [{
  id: "55",
  setor: "alimento",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (55).jpg",
  descr: "Espaguete Renata",
  de: 15,
}, {
  id: "1000",
  setor: "biscoitos",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (1000).jpg",
  descr: "Biscoito Pit-Stop",
  de: 3,
}, {
  id: "197",
  setor: "sobremesa",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (197).jpg",
  descr: "Nutella",
  de: 10,
}, {
  id: "1",
  setor: "higiene",
  foto: "Produtos/Produto (1).jpg",
  descr: "Bronzeador",
  de: 200,
}];

const filtrados = $scope.listademercadoria1.filter(obj => $scope.listaDoCarrinho.find(item => obj.id == item.id));

console.log(filtrados);
```

Comment: Obrigado Sergio. No seu exemplo realmente funciona, mas quando eu uso este código aqui, o sistema retorna no console os mesmos arrays contidos em $scope.listaDoCarrinho. Sabe o que pode estar acontecendo? Será isso pelo fato de ser em AngularJS que eu estou programando?

Comment: Você poderia me dizer qual seria o inverso disso? Caso eu precisasse manter somente o que é igual nos dois?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira se fizeres `$scope.listaMercadoriaNova = filtrados` que tenho no meu exemplo não funciona?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira pode ser que eu tenha feito ao contrário, mas talvez seja `.filter(obj => !$scope...etc`  com `!` que queiras, para só dar items que não encontre.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito grato pela ajuda, passarei o mesmo conhecimento a outros, pode deixar!